# How to print html content to a PDF with jasper reports?

Tags: html, jsf, pdf, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I'm using Primefaces 5.3 in a web app along with the Primefaces `<p:editor>` which saves its data to a database table. I would like to export/print to PDF the value data from the database with the format being ready instead of printing out codes like

`<br>` or `<ul> <li>`,  etc.

I'm using Jasper reports to create the report and then exporting to pdf, so I need to create "something" that can be printed with jasper reports that will take care of the html codes.

Comment: So effectively you ask: "how can I create a pdf from html"... search for that on stackoverflow. Hint: xhtmlrenderer works

Comment: I change the question and added additional information to clarify what I am looking for ,   thanks for responding.

Comment: So it is not  PrimeFaces related...html could have come from anywhere... I'm removing that tag and changing the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  **HtmlComponent** `<hc:html/>`

**Example**

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="230" height="110" backcolor="#ADD8E6" uuid="332dd551-e8cd-4cb0-a11f-7325f481017b"/>
    <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="FillFrame" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Top">
        <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["Hello<br/>World"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
    </hc:html>
</componentElement>
```

It will generate an image of your html.

Comment: I am having problems getting the html code to expand down the page,  I have a variable amount of input.  One entry could be 5 lines another could be 20 lines.   The hc:html does not float down the page.   Any ideas?

Comment: As stated in answer it generates an image, so the only solution is to use the image attributes as scaleType and also the clipOnOverflow attribute

Comment: so basically I'm back to figuring out how to generate output from the primefaces <p:editor> content while interpreting the html codes.  I need to use the jasper textfield as it allows expansion down the page.

Comment: I found the solution.  In jasper reports the textfield has a option called Markup that you can set to html or rtf etc...  This will interpret the field data as html or rtf etc... and since it is the textfield you also get the ability to stretch down the page.  The option in jasper studio is located under fonts.